Exporting Power BI Row-Level Security Details by Workspace
Is there a way to export the RLS configured on semantic models by workspace?
I only found this tutorial : https://www.fourmoo.com/2022/06/22/how-to-get-power-bi-row-level-security-rls-role-users-details-and... and it is not giving many details and what I understood from it, the RLS is configured in SSAS.
I want to get a list :
The workspace name
The semantic model name
The role name
The role member email
The role filter expression
